# OneSignal ID for the same user on different platforms

Tags: javascript, onesignal

First, thanks for baring with my question as well haha. Secondly.. I'm having a dilemma.

I have an app, based on Firebase, which runs on iOS / Android and Web. It basically is a chat like Facebook's messenger.

I am successfully using OneSignal for the iOS version... ( this was the first platform developed ). The issue arose when I started developing the web platform.. as per user, there is a OneSignalId generated upon registration. Issue with that is, how do I link the same account on different platforms, meaning, on iOS, say I have OneSignalId -- 1.

When I connect to the web version with an account that already exists, from a browser which is not known by OneSignal yet, I'm getting a new OneSignalId .. and that's not desired.

Is it possible to connect the OneSignalId that I already have, to the browser ?
Thanks for baring with me. I've also asked them on Intercom ( their live support ) but nobody replied as of yet.

I also don't seem to find anything inside SO or in their Docs.
Have a great evening!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each user that accesses your app or site from a different device or browser profile will get a new OneSignal playerID (unique across all OneSignal Apps).

To avoid sending notifications to the same user subscribed on multiple platforms with different Player IDs, you will need to tag the user with a unique identifier that you track in your own database and have it relate to that user's playerIDs.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/internal-database-crm

So if I log into your site or app from multiple devices, you can tag me with the UUID that you use on your system and send notifications based on that tag.

If you are using user-to-user notifications within the app, you will also need to track the playerIDs of the users because you can only target users within the app with the "include_player_ids" parameter.

For further questions please email support@onesignal.com

Thanks